# how to count array of hash based some values in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

hi how to count array of hash based some values in ruby?

example :

```
gundams = [{:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"00 raiser gundam 1/60"}, {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"strike freedom gundam 1/60"}, {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"astray red flame gundam 1/60"}, {:type=>"master grade", :name=>"exia gundam 1/100"}, {:type=>"master grade", :name=>"wing zero costum 1/100"}]
```

how to count array of hash based type? i want get result like this :

```
{"perfect grade"=>3, "master grade"=>2}
```

thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
gundams = [
  {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"00 raiser gundam 1/60"},
  {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"strike freedom gundam 1/60"},
  {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"astray red flame gundam 1/60"},
  {:type=>"master grade", :name=>"exia gundam 1/100"},
  {:type=>"master grade", :name=>"wing zero costum 1/100"}
]
Hash[gundams.group_by {|g| g[:type]}.map {
  |type, gs| [type, gs.size]
}]
# => {"perfect grade"=>3, "master grade"=>2}
```

Comment: i mean result like this {"perfect grade"=>3, "master grade"=>2}, sorry not add string.

thank you for you answer, already right :)

Comment: @tardjo, I see. I updated the answer according to the question edit.

Comment: hi @falsetru how to convert result to [3,2] ?

Comment: @tardjo, Use `Hash#values`: `Hash[gundams.group_by {|g| g[:type]}.map { |type, gs| [type, gs.size] }].values`

Comment: @tardjo, If you don't need the hash at all, just: `gundams.group_by {|g| g[:type]}.map { |type, gs| gs.size }`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @falsetru (who was faster), use [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by)

```
gundams.group_by { |e| e[:type] }.map { |k,v| [k, v.length] }
=> [["perfect grade", 3], ["master grade", 2]]
```

You can then print the array above as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
gundams = [{:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"00 raiser gundam 1/60"}, {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"strike freedom gundam 1/60"}, {:type=>"perfect grade", :name=>"astray red flame gundam 1/60"}, {:type=>"master grade", :name=>"exia gundam 1/100"}, {:type=>"master grade", :name=>"wing zero costum 1/100"}]

# Create a hash with a 0 as default value
total = Hash.new(0)

# Iterate on each value and increment for its type
gundams.each { |value| total[value[:type]] += 1 }

p total
# => {"perfect grade"=>3, "master grade"=>2}
```

Comment: hi @Martin how to convert result to array like this [3,2] ?

Answer (score 0):

Different approach to solving the problem with [`Enumerable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object)

```
gundams.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |x,hash| hash[x[:type]] += 1 }
#=> {"perfect grade"=>3, "master grade"=>2}
```